# How To Send A Private Message by Using Facebook API C# SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

does anyone know how to send private message by using My Own Facebook Apps ? I've already googled it but, it can be said none .
Would you like to share any example code or reference ?
I'd be thanks in very great Advance :)

Comment: Nope, sorry.. This is not possible. Applications simply can't send private messages like this. Imaging the spamming that would be going on if someone found a way to do this... *(shudder)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Facebook does not expose an API for this operation.